# Can I get the name of the admin who updated the record in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django and I  am trying to make an application and I am stuck with this.

I would like to get the name of the admin who updated the record and add save it. Is that possible?

Comment: If you add a field that refers to the user, yes.

Comment: If you are only concerned with the admin, the Django admin already stores a log of all user actions

Answer (score 1):

You can make an field that is a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) that refers to the user model, you can limit the options to users with `is_staff=True`. For example:

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    editor = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False,
        limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True}
    )
```

In a `CreateView` or `UpdateView`, you can then alter the field to the logged in user. For example for a `CreateView`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class MyModelCreateView(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    # …
    
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff  # only staff can access the view

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.editor = request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

In a `ModelAdmin` for the `MyModel`, you can also attach the logged in user:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.editor = request.user
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```